# Android studio1.3.1 update to 1.3.2 error

Tags: android-studio

I use MacBook Air 2015,I update my android-studio 1.3.1 to 1.3.2 ,here is the error log,

```
Contents/bin/lldb/mac/LLDB.framework/Headers/SBCommandInterpreter.h Validate    Absent  NONE
Contents/bin/lldb/mac/LLDB.framework/Headers/SBExpressionOptions.h  Validate    Absent  NONE
Contents/bin/lldb/mac/LLDB.framework/Headers/LLDB.h Validate    Absent  NONE
Contents/bin/lldb/mac/LLDB.framework/Headers/SBData.h   Validate    Absent  NONE
Contents/bin/lldb/mac/LLDB.framework/Headers/SBFileSpecList.h   Validate    Absent  NONE
Contents/bin/lldb/mac/LLDB.framework/Headers/SBInstructionList.h    Validate    Absent  NONE
Contents/bin/lldb/mac/LLDB.framework/Headers/SBTypeNameSpecifier.h  Validate    Absent  NONE
Contents/bin/lldb/mac/LLDB.framework/Headers/SBThreadPlan.h Validate    Absent  NONE
Contents/bin/lldb/mac/LLDB.framework/Headers/SBTarget.h Validate    Absent  NONE
Contents/bin/lldb/mac/LLDB.framework/Headers/SBDeclaration.h    Validate    Absent  NONE
Contents/bin/lldb/mac/LLDB.framework/Headers/SBModuleSpec.h Validate    Absent  NONE
Contents/bin/lldb/mac/LLDB.framework/Headers/SBCompileUnit.h    Validate    Absent  NONE
Contents/bin/lldb/mac/LLDB.framework/Headers/SBModule.h Validate    Absent  NONE

...
```

I don't know why.
The system ask me write more detail,because there are too many codes

Comment: same problem from 1.4.0 to 1.4.1

Answer (score 0):

I use a more stupid way, I downloaded a version to upgrade, from `Contents/bin/lldb/mac/LLDB.framework/Headers/` copy of those `*.h` files that you need to upgrade my current directory for software, and then upgrade properly, from 1.4.0 to 1.4.1, from 1.4.1 to 1.5 upgrade was successful